# PHP Warning: Attempt to read property "slug" on bool in tax query

Tags: terms, tax-query

In the tax_query, I have used the 'term' = array( $category->slug ).
I'm getting an error notice where using $category->slug, however, in the frontend it displays the slug of the term.

Please help me to debug it.

```
// Shortcode [phd_vacancies]

<?php

add_shortcode( 'phd_vacancies', function() {
    
    ob_start();
    
    global $post; // data from the current post in the WP loop
    
    $categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'country' );
    
    foreach( (array) $categories as $category ) {
        $args=array(
            'post_type' => 'job',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'orderby' => array('title' => 'DESC'),
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'country',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( $category->slug ), // PHP Warning: Attempt to read property "slug" on bool
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'position',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'phd' ),
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'current-status',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'ongoing' ),
                ),
            ),
            //'no_found_rows' => true,
            'cache_results' => false, 
        );
    }
        
$query_phd_vacancies = new WP_query( $args );

    echo '<h3>'. esc_html( $query_phd_vacancies->found_posts ) . 'PhD Positions available in' . esc_html( $category->slug ) . '</h3>(now viewing first' . esc_html( $query_phd_vacancies->post_count ) . 'only)<br>'; // PHP Warning: Attempt to read property "slug" on bool
    
    if( $query_phd_vacancies->have_posts() ) {
        while( $query_phd_vacancies->have_posts() ) {
            $query_phd_vacancies->the_post();
            ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></li>
            <?php
        }
    }else echo 'Sorry No PhD Positions found';

    wp_reset_postdata();

return ob_get_clean();

}
);
```

Comment: note that by doing `echo "variables {$inside} strings";` it's not possible to late escape the variables, making this insecure and a major security issue. There is no mechanism with this to allow an escaping function to be inserted. Use concatenation instead, e.g. `echo 'variables ' . esc_html( $inside ) . ' strings';` which is much safer and prevents injection attacks from inserting malicious code

Comment: Also, can you use the edit link to fix the indentation of your code? The broken indentation means it's difficult to read and hides the cause of the problem you asked for help with.

Comment: Hello Sir (@TomJNowell)
Thank you for your suggestion. Please look at now. I have fixed the indentation and used the concatenation.